# roboguice how to inject custom class

Tags: android, roboguice

hi i am currently using roboguice
as we know, we can use annotation to get class injected
such as

```
@InjectView(R.id.list)ListView x
```

the @inject notation works, because i extend from RoboActivity, or any Robo class

my question is
if i want to inject a custom class, called

```
public class CustomUtilManager {
}
```

i want to be able to Inject it in say RoboActivity

```
@Inject CustomUtilMananger
```

how do i do it?

my second question is, if i have a class, that is not subclass of any Robo* class

say

```
public class MyOwnClass {
}
```

how do i get the injector and inject another injectable class, such as CustomUtilManager

i.e. how can i say

```
public class MyOwnClass {
    @Inject CustomUtilManager customUtilManager;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Injection of a custom class in RoboActivity

You can inject a custom class simply using the `@Inject` annotation, but the injected class must satisfy *one* of the following conditions:

- The custom class have a default constructor (with no argument)
- The custom class have **one** injected constructor.
- The custom class has a [Provider](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki/CustomBinding#optional-using-a-provider-for-the-dependency) which handle the instantiation (more complex)

The easiest way is obviously to use a default constructor.
If you must have arguments in your constructor, it must be injected :

```
public class CustomClass {

    @Inject
    public CustomClass(Context context, Other other) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Notice the `@Inject` annotation on the constructor. The class of each argument must also be injectable by RoboGuice. Several injections for Android classes are provided out of the box by RoboGuice (for example `Context`). [Injections provided by RoboGuice](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki/Provided-Injections)

#### Injection *inside* a custom class

If you create the instance of your custom class with RoboGuice (for example with the `@Inject` annotation), all the fields marked with `@Inject` will be injected automatically.

If you want to use `new CustomClass()`, you'll have to do the injection yourself:

```
public class CustomClass {

    @Inject
    Other other;

    Foo foo;

    public CustomClass(Context context) {
        final RoboInjector injector = RoboGuice.getInjector(context);

        // This will inject all fields marked with the @Inject annotation
        injector.injectMembersWithoutViews(this);

        // This will create an instance of Foo
        foo = injector.getInstance(Foo.class);
    }

}
```

Note that you have to pass a `Context` to your constructor to be able to get the injector.