# How this field injected in github android?

Tags: android, github, roboguice

I know the github Android app using RoboGuice, and field injection needs the module to bind.

But I can not found the module that is supposed to bind the field "accountDataManager" in the **com.github.mobile.ui.user.HomeActivity**. And it is not the only one like this.

It just uses an @Inject attribute, but no module can be found.

Can anybody tell me how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using @InjectView you need to use ButterKnife view injection library. Check this link for more  [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but i want to know how the roboguice inject a normal class instance.In roboguice,inject view is similar to butterknife.

Comment: Check this question,it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257606/roboguice-how-to-inject-custom-class

Comment: The question you telle me is very helpful!I will credit you as long as i have over 15 reputation.